# TypeScript 1.5 module system - export as singleton

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

Consider the following code:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name:string) {

    }
}

let person = new Person("Dieter");

export { person };
```

If I import this person object in multiple files, am I sure that I always get the same object?

I only need one instance, the reason I use classes is for better readability.

**FYI: I use webpack to bundle all these typescript modules into one single file.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I import this person object in multiple files, am I sure that I always get the same object?

Yes. And it's a common pattern